# Unable to click on a button when Chrome controlled by webdriver

Tags: vba, selenium-webdriver

I use a mix of VBA and now Selenium to automate some of my office tasks. I have a list of serial numbers (SN) for some devices in Excel, and I am trying to write a script to open Chrome at a Dell support page, input the SN into a field to check the warranty, and return the expiration date into Excel. I cannot bypass the click button operation, usually it would work just fine, alternatively I would use submit, but this time I cannot find the solution.

I know there are APIs to use with Dell that will return the expiration date but I don't want to use the API key for some reasons.

Once I manage to sort out the click, I will pull SN values into an array and loop through instead of using ActiveCell.

Thanks for your suggestions,
Karel

Sub CheckDellWarranty()

```
' Set up Selenium
Dim driver As New WebDriver
driver.Start "chrome"

' Navigate to the specific URL
driver.Get "https://www.dell.com/support/home/fr-fr?app=products"

' Wait for Chrome to load
driver.wait 3000

' Get the value of the currently selected cell in Excel
Dim cellValue As String
cellValue = Application.ActiveCell.value

' Insert the value into the specified field using XPath
Dim inputElement As WebElement
Set inputElement = driver.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/div[5]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/form/input")
inputElement.SendKeys cellValue

' Enable the search button
driver.ExecuteScript "document.getElementById('btn-entry-select').disabled = false;"

' Find the search button by its ID
Dim searchButton As WebElement
Set searchButton = driver.FindElementById("btn-entry-select")
```

**EVEN THOUGH IT CLICKS, THE BUTTON JUST SPINS AND WILL NOT SEARCH. WHEN I OPEN CHROME MANUALLY, THE CLICK ACTION ACTUALLY FINDS THE SN.**

```
If Not searchButton Is Nothing Then
    ' Use JavaScript to trigger the click event on the search button
    driver.ExecuteScript "arguments[0].click();", searchButton
Else
    MsgBox "Failed to locate the button."
End If
Stop
```

End Sub

Comment: Any sample value of the currently selected cell in Excel for testing?

Comment: Sample SN: B5HC0T3

Comment: Welcome Karel! Please take some time to read the introduction to Stack Overflow and earn your first badge. We're a little bit different from other sites. Here's how...  https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't seems that the <kbd>Search</kbd> button is ever ***disabled***. The `<button>` element have 2 descendants:

- a `<div>` with *`style="display: none;`*
- a `<span>` with text *`Search`*

You can invoke the click on the `<span>` with text *`Search`* using either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *FindElementByCss*:

  ```
  driver.FindElementByCss("button#btn-entry-select span")
  ```
- Using *FindElementByXPath*:

  ```
  driver.FindElementByXPath("//button[@id='btn-entry-select']//span")
  ```

---

### Update

Equivalent working Python code snippet:

```
driver.get("https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-in?app=products")
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='entry-main-input-home']"))).send_keys("Latitude 10")
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button#btn-entry-select span"))).click()
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I tried, the problem is not necessarily in locating the element, but I see that the button is behaving differently when Selenium opens the browser vs. when I open the browser manually and interact with the button. So, Selenium will click on the button, but it will only spin for a bit and ultimately nothing happens. I think Dell developers want to prevent people from doing what I am trying to do to force you to register first and offer you services...

Comment: @Karel Simply add some waits before you attempt the click. I have tested the locators with Python and java both the clients and got them working.

Comment: Would you mind pasting the code here? I tried "wait" intervals but there was no change in the behavior.

Comment: Checkout the answer update with the equivalent working Python code snippet.

Comment: Thank you, I tried. In the end it looks like there is a limit to the amount of queries I can do on the Dell's site, I suppose that explains it, first time I ran the macro it worked, now the button just spins for 3 seconds and doesn't do anything. I appreciate your help! It will always find strings as "Latitude" and such, those will trigger a drop-down menu, but it won't be that friendly with one SN after another.